# understanding the continuity of thomae's function

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

[image: Here is my textbook proof of continuity of thomae's function]

Here is my textbook proof of continuity of thomae's function. My problem is why don't we consider $x_n \notin \mathbb{Q}$ when $a$ be a irrational in $(0,1)$? Can anyone please explain?

Thank you!!

Comment: If $x_n\notin\mathbb{Q}$, then $f(x_n)=0$, which is trivially within $\varepsilon$-distance from the limit for any $\varepsilon>0$. The rational case is the interesting one.

Comment: @csch2 I know the point but why is that exclude in that proof?

Comment: Most likely it was excluded as a “(why?)”-type omission where the reader is expected to fill in the detail to check their understanding.

Comment: @csch2 Got the point thank you very much