# Continuity of Thomae's function

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity, proof-explanation

[image]

Here is my textbook proof of continuity of Thomae's function. I am unable to understand further from "it suffices to show $q_n \rightarrow \infty$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ "

As I think if it happens then $x_n \rightarrow 0$ but we assumed $a$ is irrational I can't understand further please give some hint!

Comment: From two hours ago https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3965685/understanding-the-continuity-of-thomaes-function ...

Comment: @jlammy yes why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point, the author is assuming that $a\not\in\Bbb Q$ and that $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is a sequence of rational numbers which converges to $a$; furthermore, $x_n$, written in its reduced form, is $\frac{p_n}{q_n}$. The goal is to prove that$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=f(a)=0.$$Since $f(x_n)=\frac1{q_n}$, this is the same thing as asserting that $\lim_{n\to\infty}q_n=\infty$. Then, the author proves that, if this does not occur, then $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ has a subsequence $(x_{n_k})_{k\in\Bbb N}$ with a rational limit, which is impossible, since$$\lim_{k\to\infty}x_{n_k}=\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=a\notin\Bbb Q.$$

Comment: Thank you very much